# Changing Monterey display background to user folder and randomizing changes

Tags: monterey

I just upgraded to Monterey and have a couple of issues. The first is that I cannot get the display background to cycle through backgrounds in a user folder. Below are the steps I used:

1. Copied all of the files from `/System/Library/Desktop Pictures` to `~/Library/Desktop Pictures`.
2. Deleted the desktop pictures I didn't like.
3. Go to System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver
4. Select the folder *Desktop Pictures* with the *Change Picture* checked and set to 5 seconds and *Random Order* checked.
5. The preview in the top left of the dialog shows the correct background, but when I go back "<" to System Preferences or close out the dialog, the display background doesn't change from the default nor does it cycle through the default backgrounds at the requested 5 second interval.

If I click on one of the pictures inside the folder *Desktop Pictures*, the background changes but it unchecks and disable *Change Picture*.